# should close method invoked after using GroovyClassLoader to load a class?

Tags: groovy

```
GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();
Class aClass = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(classStr);
```

After parse class, should close `GroovyClassLoader` or not?

What is the result if not close it?

Comment: The cache won't be cleared; likely no other major issues. Don't know why you *wouldn't* close it.

Comment: what if I want to deallocate all classes loaded by this ClassLoader? will close do the work?

Comment: What do you mean by "deallocate"? According to [the docs](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.html#close()), which I'd recommend reading, "[a]ny classes that are already loaded are still accessible."

Comment: deallocate means remove from memory/heap space since there are no longer useful.

Comment: AFAICT and IIRC, classes are unloaded when there are no more references and the classloader that loaded it is GCed (assuming > Java 7). I could be mistaken, however, so you'd probably want to check the JLS and/or JVM specs for your version.

Comment: so question is if not invoke close, will GroovyClassLoader be GCed? if so, I won't need to invoke it, otherwise, I have to do it.

Comment: GC eligibility is dependent on references, not functions called on it (roughly speaking).